# ~ sign to import scss is searching inside node_modules in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

I have an angular project created. If I use:
`@import "~styles/variables";` 
inside a component, and have my variables file placed in `src/styles/variables`, I get:

`File to import not found or unreadable: /Users/asaadmahmood/Git/HelloWorld/node_modules/styles/_variables.scss.`

However, if I copy and paste the styles folder in my node_modules, and run the app again. It works.

Note that compass is also included like that which suggests that the `~` sign is taking it to the `node_modules` folder.
`@import "~compass-mixins/lib/compass";`

If I try to navigate to the `src` folder from the `node_modules` folder, that does not work either.

I can still import the variables file with a relative url suggesting that the file itself works.
`@import "../../styles/variables.scss";`

Any help would be appreciated. (I created a new project to test this out just to be sure my project was not messed up).

Comment: what help do you want?

Comment: I wanted help with linking the variables file with a root link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `@import "src/styles/variables";` and `@import "~src/styles/variables";` works.